# How to find position of letters in array of strings

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a problem where I need to find where letters are in a matrix of strings. The input is: `maze1=['*****','* * *','* G**','*D***','* ***']`

The expected output is a tuple of the letters coordinates. For this example, the expected output is [(2,2),(3,1)]

Here is my code so far I run into a problem when checking if the element is a letter:

```py
    treasure=[]
    for i in range(len(maze)):
        for j in range(len(maze)):
            if maze[i][j].lower().isAlpha():
                treasure[i] = maze[i][j]
    print(treasure)
```

Comment: what is the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

```
In [2]: maze1=['*****','* * *','* G**','*D***','* ***']                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

In [3]: [(i,j) for i,s in enumerate(maze1) for j,char in enumerate(s) if char.isalpha()]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[3]: [(2, 2), (3, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex

```
import re
result=[]
maze1 =['*****','* * *','* G**','*D***','* ***']
for counter, value in enumerate(maze1):
    m=re.search('([a-zA-Z]+)',value)
    if m :
        result.append((counter, m.start()))
```

Output

```
[(2, 2), (3, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your maze has 5 columns:

```
[(p//5,p%5) for p,l in enumerate("".join(maze1)) if l.isalpha()]
```

returns:

```
[(2, 2), (3, 1)]
```